# Unable to append values to specific columns in google sheets from a csv

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

```
import pandas as pd
import pygsheets
import gspread
from gspread_dataframe import set_with_dataframe
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

def csv_to_sheets():
   tokenPath ='path for service account file.json'
   scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

   credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(tokenPath, scopes=scopes)
   gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
   gs = gc.open('csv_to_gSheet')
   workSheet1 = gs.worksheet('sheet1')
   my_csv = pd.read_csv("my csv file path")
   my_csv_values = my_csv.values.tolist()
   for ele in my_csv_values:
       workSheet1.update("A" + str(len(workSheet1.get_all_values()) + 1), ele[0], value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
       workSheet1.update("S" + str(len(workSheet1.get_all_values()) + 1), ele[1:], value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")`

csv_to_sheets()
```

I have a csv which has a date column and rest are the data columns. I want to append this csv to google sheet in such a way that, my date column gets appended to column 'A' of google sheet and rest data gets appended from column 'S' and nothing in between. If I try to follow the above approach, I get a huge error while appending my data columns (last line) saying :
*gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': "Invalid value at 'data.values[0]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue)*

What should I do to do it together. Please help. Thank you in advance.

[image]

This is the input csv with first row as headers.

[image]

This is how I need my output in google sheets. The date should be in the first column and remaining data should be appended from column "S".

[image]

The input is as shown in the fig.1. The fig.3 shows the output in google sheet. The data till row 16 is already present in the sheet. We need to append the data from row 17 onwards. When we use the modification, and run the script for the 1st time, the values are correctly getting appended in col. "A" and in rest of the columns except for col. "S". (check col. "S" from row 17 to 23). But when I run the same modification script for the 2nd time, the values are correctly appended not only in col. "S" but in other columns as well. (check col. "S" from row 24 to 27)

So, I want to understand why am I getting those values in col. "S"  from row 17 to 23 which are not even present in my input and what should I do to get the correct values as sheen in row 24 to 27.

Comment: Please edit your post and include textual examples of the input CSVs and the expected output CSV.

Comment: Hi, I think this should help you understand my doubt more easily now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In the case of `for ele in my_csv_values:`, each row is uploaded and 3 API calls are used every loop.
- And, in your script, `ele[0]` is no array. And, `ele[1:]` is a 1-dimensional array. In this case, an error occurs. I thought that this might be the reason for your current error message.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
for ele in my_csv_values:
    workSheet1.update("A" + str(len(workSheet1.get_all_values()) + 1), ele[0], value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
    workSheet1.update("S" + str(len(workSheet1.get_all_values()) + 1), ele[1:], value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")`
```

#### To:

```
row = str(len(workSheet1.get_all_values()) + 1)
workSheet1.batch_update([
    {"range": "A" + row,"values": [[r[0]] for r in my_csv_values]},
    {"range": "S" + row,"values": [r[1:] for r in my_csv_values]},
  ],
  value_input_option="USER_ENTERED",
)
```

- By this modification, this process can be done by 2 API calls.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it is not throwing any error and the values are getting appended at correct columns but when I execute it for the first time, it gives me different values in "S" column -> [02-22-1900,02-28-1900,05-09-1900,06-09-1900,02-24-1900,03-01-1900,02-07-1900] and when I execute it again without changing anything, it gives proper output as shown in the output fig. Where is it going wrong?

Comment: @Kartikeya Kawadkar Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate the situation of your reply. When I tested my proposed script using a sample CSV data, the 1st column of CSV data is put into column "A". And, the columns after the 2nd column are put from column "S". I think that this is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for my poor skill. But, I would like to support you. So, in order to correctly replicate your current issue, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? I would like to confirm it.

Comment: No, please its not your poor skill. See the data is correctly getting segregated as 1st column from csv to column "A" and columns after 2nd column are put from column "S". Lets focus on col. "S". When I execute the above modification for the 1st time, col. "S" gets appended with the values listed in the above comment and not with the original values -> [54,60,130,161...] and when I run the same code again I get my original values in col. "S" as-> [54,60,130,161...]. So, why is that happening? I hope this wil make you understand in a much better way, if not, I'll explain again. Thank you.

Comment: @Kartikeya Kawadkar Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience again. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide your sample CSV data as text data? Using your sample CSV data, I would like to replicate your current issue. When I tested a sample CSV data created from your showing image, the 1st column is put to column "A". And, the columns after the 2nd column are put from column "S". Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I deeply apologize for my poor skill, again.

Comment: @Kartikeya Kawadkar I'm worried that I might not be able to correctly understand your current issue, because of my poor English skill. So, in order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the current sample input and output situations as the images?

Comment: Hi, I have edited my post. Please let me know if need any more clarification on the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249543/discussion-between-kartikeya-kawadkar-and-tanaike).

Comment: @Kartikeya Kawadkar Thank you for replying. About `But when I run the same modification script for the 2nd time, the values are correctly appended not only in col. "S" but in other columns as well. (check col. "S" from row 24 to 27)` and your added image, if my understanding is correct, I thought that the number format of the cells of "S17:S" of your Spreadsheet is required to be set as the number. In your actual Spreadsheet, the number format of the cells "S17:S" might be the reason for your current issue. How about manually setting the cell format?